# How to link a javascript object property to another property of the same object?

Tags: javascript, object, hyperlink, properties, interface

Is there a way to link the value of one object property to the value of another?

The idea is, that I have something like an excepted interface so I need the `propertys.name` and `.value` for my obj. In this special case name is easily constructed from value (value is an array and name is `array.toString()`)

I could use `obj.value.toString()` instead of value but the code needs to use `obj.name` to make it work for all cases.

I tried this code, but it does not produce the result I want. How could I achieve the desired behavior?

```
obj = {value: array, name: this.value.toString()}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [getter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
var obj = {
  value: array,
  get name() {
    return this.value.toString();
  }
};
console.log(obj.value.toString() === obj.name); // true
```

You can even extend this to use a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) if need be.

```
var obj = {
  value: array,
  get name() {
    return this.value.toString();
  },
  set name(val) {
    this.value = val.split(','); // or any other operation you may need
  }
};
obj.name = '1,2,3';
console.log(obj.value); // ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: I didn't know that javascript had getters. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you need name to do something, you'd need a function:

```
obj = {value: ['foo','bar'], name: function() { return this.value.toString() }}


console.log(obj.value)
console.log(obj.name())
```

> ["foo","bar"]
>   foo,bar

Comment: this does not work because you have to use obj.name(). And I can't use the braces as my code expects a property not a function. This could work, but I would have to change all my code for this. The above answer solves my problem perfectly

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't access a property upon initialization of the object. You can however set it after the creation of the obj.

```
obj = {value: array, name:null}
obj.name = obj.value.toString();
```

Comment: well the above solution does the trick. Your answer doesn't work for me because I would have to manually keep value and name in sync...

Comment: Just make sure you do a null check on value in that getter method.

Answer (score -1):

Use a getter:

```js
var obj = {
    value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    get name(){
        return this.value.toString()
    }
}

console.log(obj.value)
console.log(obj.name)
```